# Word press Short code customization

Tags: wordpress, html, plugins, shortcode

Ive downloaded a theme from theme forest called "Gather version 2.6" for conference/venue website theme.

In the theme there is a button for "reserve my seat" the short code in the editor for this is: [paypal_reg_modal button="Book Event" form_title="Event Registration" submit="Book Event"][/paypal_reg_modal]
(i have renamed the "reserve my seat" to "book event")

When clicking this, a form pops up on the page where the user can input their info, but i want this button to display a form from 123contact form.

Is there a way for me to change this code or convert the URL from the 123contactform site so the user will fill out my specific form instead of the preset?

I know there is a plug-in to create my own button but i would like the user to stay on site rather than get taken to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to debug code then find **add_shortcode** function and check tag name in function after that you will get a render function from there you can customize the code and also you change your shortcode tag(name).

Hope this will help